# Looking for a pastebin supporting Markdown

Tags: markdown, pastebin

I have gotten used to the text editor and format of Stack Exchange (Markdown), which is much better to describe a question than mail editor.

Sometimes I want to describe a problem/question to a colleague or my supervisor, but I do not want to send them a link of Stack Exchange directly. Does anyone know if there is a PasteBin site where we could paste some texts in Markdown, and get a link?

Comment: Similar question on softwarerecs.SE:
[Is there a pastebin for Markdown?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/is-there-a-pastebin-for-markdown)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [wrttn.in](http://wrttn.in)

> Wrttn is a simple notepad with many useful features, the main one
>   being that you can save as much text as you like while taking
>   advantage of the formatting options markup languages such as Textile
>   or Markdown give you.
>
> This means that you can use wrttn to jot down ideas, write an article,
>   an essay, a collection of media (more on this later) or anything your
>   heart desires: both privately (by not sharing the link), or publicly
>   (by sharing the link).

I created a test wrttn and you can view the public version [here](http://wrttn.in/643a8f)

There is also an admin url where you can edit the markdown which can be viewed [here](http://wrttn.in/admin/8cbf648b061f)

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, do you know how to set up "Markdown" as default, instead of "Textile"?

Comment: @SoftTimur on the homepage click on the `Controls and Options`button